# why arent my labels popping up when placed, simular to other widgets?

Tags: python, tkinter, widget, label

ive been working on a duplicate image detector for a bit now, and ive run into an error that is only encountered for me, as ive seen nobody else have this error when they test it. the error is in the function `showImages()` where i have 3 labels that i want to use, yet **only** those three labels dont work. the buttons and the images work just fine, but the labels do not. i have been pulling my hair out for the past couple days trying to find what is making these 3 labels not pop up.
the code should would fine on other computers, granted you have the modules. to test, you need 2 folders with images, and some of those images should have a duplicate in its counterpart folder.

```py
from tkinter import filedialog
import cv2, numpy, os, math
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import tkinter as tk
root = Tk()
root.configure(background="black")
canvas = Canvas(root, bd=0, bg = 'black', width = 1920, height = 1080)
canvas.pack()
canvas.configure(bg = 'black')
file1 = ''
file2 = ''
identicalImages1 = []
identicalImages2 = []
directories = []
blacklisted = [".gif" ,".avi",".exe", ".wav", ".avf", ".mov", ".mp4", ".webm", ".flv", ".txt", ".swf", ".log", ".url"]
fonta = 'Terminal' 
text_color = 'lime'
indecs = 0
leniancy = 4 #default

label1 = Label(root, bg = 'black', fg = text_color, text= '', font = (fonta, 30))  # 5 given labels
label2 = Label(root, bg = 'black', fg = text_color, text= '', font = (fonta, 30))
label3 = Label(root, bg = 'black', fg = text_color, text= '', font = (fonta, 30))
label4 = Label(root, bg = 'black', fg = text_color, text= '', font = (fonta, 30))
label5 = Label(root, bg = 'black', fg = text_color, text= '', font = (fonta, 30))

image1 = Label(root, bg = 'black', fg = text_color, font = (fonta, 30)) # 5 given images
image2 = Label(root, bg = 'black', fg = text_color, font = (fonta, 30))
image3 = Label(root, bg = 'black', fg = text_color, font = (fonta, 30))
image4 = Label(root, bg = 'black', fg = text_color, font = (fonta, 30))
image5 = Label(root, bg = 'black', fg = text_color, font = (fonta, 30))

button1 = Button(root, bg = 'black', fg = text_color, font = (fonta, 30)) # 5 given buttons
button2 = Button(root, bg = 'black', fg = text_color, font = (fonta, 30))
button3 = Button(root, bg = 'black', fg = text_color, font = (fonta, 30))
button4 = Button(root, bg = 'black', fg = text_color, font = (fonta, 30))
button5 = Button(root, bg = 'black', fg = text_color, font = (fonta, 30))

slider1 = Scale(root,bg = 'black', fg = text_color)
slider2 = Scale(root,bg = 'black', fg = text_color)
def forgor(): # resets every widget when swapping pages
    try:
        label1.place_forget()
        label1.config(font = (fonta, 30))
        label2.place_forget()
        label2.config(font = (fonta, 30))
        label3.place_forget()
        label3.config(font = (fonta, 30))
        label4.place_forget()
        label4.config(font = (fonta, 30))
        label5.place_forget()
        label5.config(font = (fonta, 30))
        button1.place_forget()
        button1.config(font = (fonta, 30))
        button2.place_forget()
        button2.config(font = (fonta, 30))
        button3.place_forget()
        button3.config(font = (fonta, 30))
        button4.place_forget()
        button4.config(font = (fonta, 30))
        button5.place_forget()
        button5.config(font = (fonta, 30))
        image1.place_forget()
        image2.place_forget()
        image3.place_forget()
        image4.place_forget()
        image5.place_forget()
        slider1.place_forget()
        slider1.place_forget()
    except:
        pass

def start1():          # main menu
    global file1, file2
    file1 = ''
    file2 = ''
    forgor()
    label1.config(bd = 2, text = "IMAGE DUPE COMPARER")
    label1.place(x = 960, y = 50, anchor= 'center') # title name

    label2.config(bd = 2)
    label2.place(x = 480, y = 530, anchor= 'center') # folder 1 name

    label3.config(bd = 2)
    label3.place(x = 1440, y = 530, anchor= 'center') # folder 2 name

    button1.config(text = "folder 1", command = lambda: ask_for_folder(1)) # folder 1 button
    button1.place(x = 480, y = 590, anchor= 'center')

    button2.config(text = "folder 2", command = lambda: ask_for_folder(2)) # folder 2 button
    button2.place(x = 1440, y = 590, anchor= 'center')

    button3.config(text = "Go!", command = start2)
    button3.place(x = 960, y = 700, anchor= 'center') # initiate button, dont worry about the window turning to (not responding) all its doing is the image comparing stuff

    button4.config(text = "Options", command = options_menu) # options to change things
    button4.place(x = 960, y = 780, anchor= 'center')

    button5.config(text = "Exit", command = root.destroy) # exit button
    button5.place(x = 960, y = 860, anchor= 'center')

    print(leniancy)

def options_menu():
    forgor() # resets all widgets
    label1.config(text = "Image Leniency\n(the lower, the more accurate, while the higher, the more possible images detected)", font = (fonta, 20))
    label1.place(x = 960, y = 100, anchor= 'center')

    slider1.set(leniancy) # to set it to what was previously set, or the default
    slider1.config(bd = 0 ,from_ = 1, to = 10, tickinterval = 1, variable = leniancy, length = 400, orient = HORIZONTAL, font = (fonta, 20), command = lenancy)
    slider1.place(x = 960, y = 170, anchor= 'center')

    button1.config(text = "Save & Exit", command = start1) #back to main menu
    button1.place(x = 960, y = 860, anchor= 'center')
def start2():                                    # second part of the code [BUG] when you click the go button without specifying folders, it breaks. its an easy fix but thats not at the top of my list right now 
    global folder1, folder2
    forgor()
    folder1 = get_average_colors(file1)
    folder2 = get_average_colors(file2)
    for i in folder1.keys():
        for j in folder2.keys():
            compare_images(i, j)
    showImages(identicalImages1[indecs], identicalImages2[indecs])
def ask_for_folder(folder):
    global file1, file2
    if folder == 1:
        try:
            file1 = filedialog.askdirectory().replace("\\", "/")
            label2.config(text= file1[[i for i, c in enumerate(file1) if c == "/"][-1] + 1:])
        except IndexError:
            label2.config(text= '')
    elif folder == 2:
        try:
            file2 = filedialog.askdirectory().replace("\\", "/")
            label3.config(text= file2[[i for i, c in enumerate(file2) if c == "/"][-1] + 1:])
        except IndexError:
            label3.config(text= '')  
def lenancy(value): # used in the menu
    global leniancy 
    leniancy = value
def swag_sort(stri): # used for sorting images that were all saved as the same name, with the ending being an index of those images, so like: image (1).jpg
    try:
        return int(stri[stri.index('(') + 1:stri.index(')')])
    except:
        return stri 
def remove_non_ascii(s): # removes all the weird characters that arent gonna work
    try:
        return "".join(c for c in s if ord(c)<128)
    except:
        return s
def tell_if_non_ascii(s):
    for i in s:
        if ord(i)>128:
            return True
        else:
            return False
def round(x, interval):       # the main way to change the leniency of image checking, for stuff like image corruption
    return (-x % interval + x)
def get_average_colors(currentDirectory): # gets every image in the folder, divides those images by 4, then gets the average rgb color for the 4 quadrant images. the 4 quadrant stuff is usually to help greyscale images
    global directories
    average = {}
    os.chdir(currentDirectory)
    directories.append(currentDirectory)
    list1 = [i for i in [i for i in [i for i in os.listdir(currentDirectory) if "." in i]] if i[i.index('.'):] not in blacklisted] # removes shortcuts and folders from the list of images
    Placeholder = {}
    for i in list1:
        if tell_if_non_ascii(i):
            Placeholder[i] = remove_non_ascii(i)
    for i in Placeholder.keys():
        os.rename(i,Placeholder[i])
    list1 = [remove_non_ascii(i) for i in list1]
    try:
        list1 = sorted(list1, key=swag_sort)
    except:
        pass
    for image in list1: # splits every image in the list into 4 parts, then gets the average pixel of each
        print(image, end="                                                                                            \r")
        myimg = cv2.imread(image)
        (h, w) = myimg.shape[:2]
        (cX, cY) = (int(w) // 2, int(h) // 2)
        imgs = [myimg[0:cY, 0:cX],myimg[0:cY, cX:w],myimg[cY:h, 0:cX],myimg[cY:h, cX:w]] # goes from top left, to top right, then bottom left, then bottom right
        avg_color = []
        for i in imgs:
            avg_color_per_row = numpy.average(i, axis=0)
            avg_color.append([round(i, leniancy) for i in numpy.average(avg_color_per_row, axis=0)]) 
        average[image] = avg_color
    return average
def compare_images(image1, image2):          # image comparison algorithm
    global identicalImages1, identicalImages2
    list1 = folder1[image1]
    list2 = folder2[image2]
    p = []
    for i, j in zip(list1, list2):
        d = math.sqrt((i[0] - j[0])**2 + (i[1] - j[1])**2 + (i[2] - j[2])**2)
        p.append(int((1 - d / (255 * math.sqrt(3))) * 100)) # stinky math, basically simplified version of a whole bunch of processes in one to get the percentage of how off it is
   #if set(p) == {100}:       #for correctness and nothing else
    if p.count(100) >= 4:     #1 should be changeable, and should be a weight if i ever am gonna find out how to correctly make an ai
        identicalImages1.append(image1)
        identicalImages2.append(image2)
        print(str(p) + "100% chance of {} being a duplicate to {}".format(image1, image2))
    else:
        print(str(p) + "% chance of {} being a duplicate to {}".format(image1, image2), end="                                                                                            \r")
    return p

def showImages(img1, img2): # tkinter part that lets you compare images 
    forgor()
    imag1 = (Image.open(directories[0] + '/' + img1))
    imag2 = (Image.open(directories[1] + '/' + img2))
    resized_image1 = imag1.resize((960, 540), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    resized_image2 = imag2.resize((960, 540), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    new_image1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(resized_image1)
    new_image2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(resized_image2)
    ratio = str(identicalImages1.index(img1)) + "/" + str(len(identicalImages1))

    image1.place(x = 0, y = 20)
    image1.config(image= new_image1) # image 1
    image1.image = new_image1

    image2.place(x = 960, y = 20)
    image2.config(image= new_image2) # image 2
    image2.image = new_image2

    label1.place(x = 0, y = 20)
    label1.config(font=(fonta, 20), text= str(img1)) #image 1 name, displayed in the top left corner of image 1

    label2.place(x = 960, y = 20)
    label2.config(font=(fonta, 20), text= str(img2)) #image 2 name, displayed in the top left corner of image 2
    
    label3.place(x = 960, y = 530, anchor= 'center') # displays how far you are through the grading process
    label3.config(font = (fonta, 20), text = ratio)

    button1.place(x = 480, y = 590, anchor= 'center')
    button1.config(font=(fonta, 20), text= "delete {}".format(str(img1)), command= lambda: destroyed_image(img1, directories[0], replaced())) # destroys the image1
    
    button2.place(x = 1440, y = 590, anchor= 'center')
    button2.config(font=(fonta, 20), text= "delete {}".format(str(img2)), command= lambda: destroyed_image(img2, directories[1], replaced())) # destroys the image2

    button3.place(x = 960, y = 590, anchor= 'center')
    button3.config(text = "pass", font=(fonta, 20), command= replaced) # passes both images

    button4.place(x = 960, y = 670, anchor= 'center')
    button4.config(text = "delete both", font=(fonta, 20), command= lambda: destroyed_image(img1, directories[0], destroyed_image(img2, directories[1], replaced()))) # runs the destroy twice with an, in my opinion, genius way to incorperate both and still replace the images
def replaced(): # when done with it
    global indecs
    indecs += 1
    try:
        showImages(identicalImages1[indecs], identicalImages2[indecs])
    except IndexError: # when at the end of the list
        start1()
def destroyed_image(imag, directory, diff): # destroys all the images that are detected simular ahead of it, if it was chosen to be deleted WORK IN PROGRESS
    try:
        for i in [index for index, element in enumerate(identicalImages1) if element == imag][1:]:
            identicalImages1.pop(i)
            identicalImages2.pop(i)
    except:
        try:
            for i in [index for index, element in enumerate(identicalImages2) if element == imag][1:]:
                identicalImages1.pop(i)
                identicalImages2.pop(i)
        except:
            pass
    try:
        os.remove(directory + '/' + imag)
    except:
        print("image already deleted or doesnt exist")
    diff
start1()
try:
    mainloop()
except:
    pass
```

Comment: have you tried not placing labels in the same coordinates as those images? they should be visible since they are placed after the images but just in case, try placing those labels on a side or somewhere

Comment: yes, ive tried it back and forth, in every position where there is nothing else

Comment: are you sure that those labels have any text? try `label1.tk_raise()` at the end of that function, also provide a [mre]

Comment: You've posted what looks like way more code than is necessary to reproduce this problem. Please try to reduce the code down to a [mcve].

Comment: you could keep labels on list (instead separated variables `label1`, `label2`, etc) and then you could use `for`-loop to run functions on all labels. And the same with buttons. This way code could be much shorter.

Comment: the bigger mistake is `except: pass` - you may have error which could explain all your problem but you can't see it because you use `pass`. You should at least display error - `except Exception as ex: print(ex)`

Comment: ive replaced every use of ```except: pass``` with correct code, however it doesnt run into a single error for anything to do with labels, and the errors it does run into are intentional

Answer (score 0):

i found the answer just a bit ago, apparently no matter the order you place it in, which ever widget was defined first goes on the bottom, and i put my labels to be defined first. so, the labels were, no matter what, being placed behind the image, and the image was resized so it still had the dimensions of the original image, just the pixels of the image were resized. so they would hide underneath the images no matter what.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).